# Erro PHP ’WPLANG’ - assumed '’WPLANG’'

Tags: php, wordpress

Boa noite. Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento PHP\WordPress. Eu baixei um site em WP\PHP para fazer alterações, então ao chamar no localhost, recebo a seguinte mensagem:
Warning: Use of undefined constant ’WPLANG’ - assumed '’WPLANG’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\novosite\wp-config.php on line 75

Já olhei na linha 75 e não entendi o problema. vcs poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Dizer qual é o erro sem o código é meio difícil, mas esse tipo de alerta é típico de quando você tenta utilizar uma variável sem o cifrão. Nesse caso, se não for encontrado nenhuma constante com o nome `WPLANG`, o PHP procura pela variável de nome `$WPLANG` e deixa o aviso. Se você queria utilizar uma constante, certifique-se que o PHP consegue acessa-la, se você queria utilizar uma variável, adicione o cifrão no nome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sem ler o seu código não da para te ajudar. O máximo que eu posso fazer é supor uma cenário baseado na mensagem de erro onde na linha 75 do seu código tenha algo assim:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'Aqui_está_o_erro!');
```

Então caso você tenha a definição de idioma Português Brasil instalada, para corrigir um erro supostamente baseado num cenário hipotético seria:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'pt_BR');
```

Caso você não tenha a definição de idioma Português Brasil instalada então para corrigir um erro supostamente baseado num cenário hipotético seria:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'en_US');
```

Mas isso é especulação baseada na mensagem de erro. Agora quando você publicar a fonte com o erro eu posso dizer seguramente qual o erro e qual a solução.

Comment: Olá Augusto, Boa noite!

O erro que está dando é esse.

Warning: Use of undefined constant ’WPLANG’ - assumed '’WPLANG’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\novosite\wp-config.php on line 75

Warning: Use of undefined constant ‘en_US’ - assumed '‘en_US’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\novosite\wp-config.php on line 75

Alterei a versão, colocando-a para 'en_US' e a página fica em branco e não sobe o site.

Comment: @RodrigoJúlio Comente essa linha e compile. `#define ('WPLANG', 'pt_Br');`

Comment: comentei e continua em branco... eu baixei esse arquivo ftp e deu uns xabus. estou vendo que tenho que baixar novamente.

Comment: Isso me chamou a atenção **Use of undefined constant ‘en_US’ - assumed '‘en_US’'**. Parece que nenhum  pacote de idioma está instalado. Nem o padrão en_US. Parece que   está corrompido.

Comment: entendi! vou baixar o arquivo novamente pq estou achando que não baixou tudo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.